# how to implement import semantics into the current block scope?

Tags: perl

The documentation of `use` indicates that:

> Some ... pseudo-modules import semantics into the current block scope (like strict or integer , unlike ordinary modules, which import symbols into the current package (which are effective through the end of the file).

Similarly, `autodie`

> Replace functions with ones that succeed or die with lexical scope

How to implement import semantics into the current block scope with ordinary modules?

Comment: Did you look at any sources, like say http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RJBS/perl-5.12.3/lib/strict.pm ?

Comment: It was not obvious to me how to do it after taking a quick look at autodie and Fatal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`strict` and `warnings` are implemented using some special flag variables that don't contain room for user pragmas.  Starting with perl 5.10, you can write your own lexically scoped pragmas.  [perlpragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpragma.html) contains information on how to do so.  You can also browse the source of existing pragmatic modules.